# Emoji-picker-react works but with errors in the console when opening

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a social media application where users can add posts with emojis, backgrounds and images like on a facebook post.  The emoji picker works fine but when I click the image to open the picker, I get the following error in the console.

```
GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-datasource-apple/img/apple/64/2642-fe0f.png

GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-datasource-apple/img/apple/64/2695-fe0f.png

GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-datasource-apple/img/apple/64/2640-fe0f.png
```

I can add and emoji's and submit the post and they work perfectly but I'd really like to get rid of this error.  I'm using emoji-picier-react version 4.4.8.  The tutorial I used to build it was using v 3.5.1 so I tried downgrading.  I delete node_modules and the package-lock.json and reinstalled everthing but get different errors.

Here is the code to the EmojiPickerBackgrounds.js file where the picker is called from:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Picker from 'emoji-picker-react';

const EmojiPickerBackgrounds = ({
  text,
  user,
  setText,
  type2,
  background,
  setBackground,
}) => {
  const [picker, setPicker] = useState(false);
  const [showBg, setShowBg] = useState(false);
  const textRef = useRef(null);
  const bgRef = useRef(null);
  const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    textRef.current.selectionEnd = cursorPosition;
  }, [cursorPosition]);

  const handleEmoji = ({ emoji }) => {
    const ref = textRef.current;
    ref.focus();
    const start = text.substring(0, ref.selectionStart);
    const end = text.substring(ref.selectionStart);
    const newText = start + emoji + end;
    setText(newText);
    setCursorPosition(start.length + emoji.length);
  };

  const postBackgrounds = [
    '../../../images/postBackgrounds/1.jpg',
    '../../../images/postBackgrounds/2.jpg',
    '../../../images/postBackgrounds/3.jpg',
    '../../../images/postBackgrounds/4.jpg',
    '../../../images/postBackgrounds/5.jpg',
    '../../../images/postBackgrounds/6.jpg',
    '../../../images/postBackgrounds/7.jpg',
    '../../../images/postBackgrounds/8.jpg',
    '../../../images/postBackgrounds/9.jpg',
  ];

  const backgroundHandler = (i) => {
    bgRef.current.style.backgroundImage = `url(${postBackgrounds[i]})`;
    setBackground(postBackgrounds[i]);
    bgRef.current.classList.add('bgHandler');
  };

  const removeBackground = (i) => {
    bgRef.current.style.backgroundImage = '';
    setBackground('');
    bgRef.current.classList.remove('bgHandler');
  };
  return (
    <div className={type2 ? 'images_input' : ''}>
      <div className={!type2 ? 'flex_center' : ''} ref={bgRef}>
        <textarea
          ref={textRef}
          maxLength="250"
          value={text}
          placeholder={`What's on your mind, ${user.first_name}`}
          className={`post_input ${type2 ? 'input2' : ''}`}
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          style={{
            paddingTop: `${
              background
                ? Math.abs(textRef.current.value.length * 0.1 - 32)
                : '0'
            }%`,
          }}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div className={!type2 ? 'post_emojis_wrap' : ''}>
        {picker && (
          <div
            className={`comment_emoji_picker ${
              type2 ? 'movepicker2' : 'rlmove'
            }`}
          >
            <Picker onEmojiClick={handleEmoji} />
          </div>
        )}
        {!type2 && (
          <img
            src="../../../icons/colorful.png"
            alt="Color Picker"
            onClick={() => setShowBg((prev) => !prev)}
          />
        )}
        {!type2 && showBg && (
          <div className="post_backgrounds">
            <div
              className="no_bg"
              onClick={() => {
                removeBackground();
              }}
            >
              {postBackgrounds.map((bg, i) => (
                <img
                  src={bg}
                  key={i}
                  alt=""
                  onClick={() => backgroundHandler(i)}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        <i
          className={`emoji_icon_large ${type2 ? 'moveleft' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => setPicker((prev) => !prev)}
        ></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmojiPickerBackgrounds;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a **solution** for this. I just added emojiStyle prop to the EmojiPicker component and the value for that prop is **EmojiStyle.NATIVE** or **EmojiStyle.GOOGLE** or **EmojiStyle.TWITTER**. Don't use **EmojiStyle.APPLE** or **EmojiStyle.FACEBOOK** because there is also an console log error.

Make sure install the latest version emoji picker first (version 4.4.10 or 4.4.11) and import the EmojiStyle.

Here's the full example code in my current Next.js project.

```
import { EmojiClickData, EmojiStyle } from "emoji-picker-react";

const EmojiPicker = dynamic(() => {
  return import('emoji-picker-react');
},{ ssr: false });

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <EmojiPicker 
           emojiStyle={EmojiStyle.NATIVE} 
           onEmojiClick={handleEmojiClick} 
        />
    )
}
```

I hope this works for you too.
This is surely a bug (404 means not found).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).